# Beamer - Fix a sentence on the TOP RIGHT corner under the title

Tags: positioning, box

I would like to have an information on a box on the top left corner of my slides (under the title part) but I am not getting it right. I tried with tikz in this way, but it doesn't move it, it leave it on the center of the slide.

This is the standard slide with my try that do not work.

```
    \documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{biolinum}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    
    \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
    \usetheme[nofirafonts]{focus}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}{Test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east)  {UV  regulator:  $\Lambda$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: this is the frame with the suggestion from js bibra but it "overwrite" the title line. I would like to write just below it (keeping the style of the previous frame)

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{biolinum}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{tikz}
        \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
    \usetheme[nofirafonts]{focus}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
            
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        %\fill[red] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
        \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east)  {UV  regulator:  $\Lambda$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{frame}
    
    \end{document}
```

EDIT: here is the sketch of my idea:

[image]

Comment: your code does not compile

Comment: is there something else you required in the answer

Comment: yes, I edited to further explain

Comment: it would be helpful if you could add a handrawn sketch of your desired output--also your code is not complete without `\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was not compiling correctly for me--I substituted some dummy text --please use `[remember picture, overlay]`with `tikzpicture` in such scenarios

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biolinum}
\usepackage{microtype}
%
%\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
%\usetheme[nofirafonts]{focus}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \fill[red] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
    \node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east)  {north east corner};
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**edit -- using the calc library you can position your text at any point on the current page/ frame**

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biolinum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usetheme[nofirafonts]{focus}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}{Test}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=north east] at ($(current page.north east)-(0,1.5)$){UV  
         regulator:  $\Lambda$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        BLA BLA
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that in this way you "overwrite" on the style of the slides. And in the top left corner of the slide I have the title line.
I would like to write something just below it. I will now edit the question to better explain it.

Comment: please see the edit above-- this should meet the requirement shown in your sketch

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you a lot for all the help